# Keep focus on dropdown list while writing in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am kind of new in AngularJS and Bootstrap, and would like to get some help.

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdownlist which filters by input text.
here is my code:

```
<input id="SelectedCountry" type="text" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" ng-model="Pass" autocomplete="off"  />
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li data-ng-repeat="r in countrycodes | MyFilter *my filter in the app.filter. works fine*"><a href="#" data-ng-click="selectedcountry.value=r.value">{{r.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like that everytime the user clicks on the down arrowkey the focus will be on the dropdownlist (which is not happening automatically, why?), so I wrote this code:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.dropdown', function (event) {
    var dropdown = $(event.target);
    $("input").keydown(function (e) {
        if ((e.which && e.which == 40) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 40)) {
            // Set aria-expanded to true
            dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu').attr('aria-expanded', true);

            // Set focus on the first link in the dropdown
            dropdown.find('.dropdown-menu li:first-child a').focus();

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that when the user presses the down arrow key the focus is not on the input text any more, so he can't keep writing.

How can I make a dynamic dropdownlist where the user can keep writing while the focus is on the menu?
I already tried using the Jquery filter but it didn't work out because I have to use AngularJs so I can trigger the data-ng-click while the user chooses his option, and In addition I get the options with the data-ng-repeat so I can't use the default "select" and "option" tags in html.
Everywhere I searched for a solution says that can't be to elements focused at the same time. perhaps there is another option? because there are alot of websites with this case?

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. It can't be 2 elements focused at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't focus on the dropdown list automatically because **it's not supposed to**. When the user presses up or down in an ordinary input field (with no event listener and special stuff like that), the cursor is supposed to only move to the far left or to the far right, depending on what has been pressed.

Also, there is no way for you to keep them focused at the same time. Only one element can be in focus. What you can do is keep a variable that says which dropdown list element is "focused" and have an event listener for the user pressing enter, which will execute whatever it's supposed to regarding that list element. That variable will change when up or down is pressed. Also, you should use event.preventDefault() to stop the cursor from going to the left/right if up/down is pressed. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

And one more thing. In order to simulate a click on the desired dropdown list item, you can use [jQuery's trigger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

**UPDATE 2**

I made a sample code, because I don't know how else to show what I mean. Also, I haven't used jQuery - everything is vanilla JS. Therefore I didn't use the trigger function either. Feel free to play around with it or judge it (that's what I've made it for too):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #content {
                width: 500px;
                margin-top: 30px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #search-list {

            }

            #search-list li {
                display: block;
                width: 200px;
                height: 40px;
                line-height: 40px;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #666;
            }


            #search-list li.focused {
                background: #aaa;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <input id="search-input" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type text here"  />
            <ul id="search-list">
                <li>Meow</li>
                <li>Roar</li>
                <li>Mewore</li>
                <li>Foo</li>
                <li>Bar</li>
                <li>Bartender</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="log">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var items = document.getElementById('search-list').getElementsByTagName('li');

            document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);

            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                items[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandler );
                items[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOutHandler );
                items[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler );
            }

            function getElementIndex(elem) {
                var children = event.target.parentNode.childNodes;
                var idx=-1;
                for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                    if(children[i].nodeType == 1) {
                        idx++;
                        if(children[i] == elem) return idx;
                    }
                }
            }

            function mouseOverHandler(event) {
                var idx = getElementIndex(event.target);

                if(currentItem != -1) items[currentItem].className = "";

                event.target.className = "focused";
                currentItem = idx;
            }

            function mouseOutHandler(event) {
                var idx = getElementIndex(event.target);
                event.target.className = "";
                if(currentItem == idx) {
                    currentItem = -1;
                }
            }

            function clickHandler(event) {
                document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<p>' + event.target.innerText + '</p>';
            }

            var currentItem = -1;

            function keyDownHandler(event) {
                var keyPressed = event.which || event.keyCode;
                if(keyPressed == 38) {
                    //up
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if(currentItem >= 0) {
                        items[currentItem].className = "";
                    }
                    currentItem = (currentItem == -1) ? (items.length-1) : (currentItem-1);
                    if(currentItem >= 0) {
                        items[currentItem].className = "focused";
                    }
                } else if(keyPressed == 40) {
                    //down
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if(currentItem >= 0) {
                        items[currentItem].className = "";
                    }
                    currentItem = (currentItem == items.length - 1) ? -1 : (currentItem+1);
                    if(currentItem >= 0) {
                        items[currentItem].className = "focused";
                    }
                } else if(keyPressed == 13) {
                    //enter
                    if(currentItem == -1) document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<p>' + event.target.value + '</p>';
                    else document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '<p>' + items[currentItem].innerText + '</p>';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, thankyou for your answer.
second, you said "What you can do is keep a variable that says which dropdown list element is "focused"". 
how can I know what dropdown list element is focused at the time?
I tried a few things and nothing succeeded.

Comment: And another thing, if the dropdownlist and the input field can't be focused at the same time, how are there alot of dynamic searchboxes (the simplest example is Google's searchbox or Facebook) where you can focus the options while you keep typing in the input text?